# Excel: Updating one WS from another WS

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large spreadsheet (RawData) with lots of data and I have been creating tabs in the workbook to view this data in a more userfriendly way using INDEX/MATCH functions (Faster than VLOOKUP?).
I now would like to be able to update the underlying data sheet (RawData) from the tabs. In the tabs I have the current values side by side with cells in an adjacent column where I aim to be able to enter a new value for one or more of the current. I have come up with a roundabout way to do this BUT without any finesse.

Any suggestions for me how to do this with some finesse. Updtae could either happen at each of the entries via hitting "Enter" or by a click of a "Update" button that updates all edited fields in the sheet.

Edit: The way I am doing it tody is by "brute force". I use a listbox to select a record (row), all data shown in tabs comes form this row. I also know for each value on a tab which column it comes from, it is hardcoded into the INDEX/MATCH statement. So for updates I use hidden fields containing current row and each value's columnnumber. I pick these numbers from the sheet with VBA and update the value. I would like to get away from these hidden fields!

This is the simple code I have for now, and it is working but ...

```
Sub Update()
Dim NewValue As Variant


  'Current record in RawData is always found in cell D5 on the Summary Sheet
  aRow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Cells(5, 3).Value

  For i = 1 To 20 'max 20 rows i Module that can be updated
    'Column to update in rawdata read from col M (Hidden value)
    aCol = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Cells(i + 8, 13).Value
    'New value in adjacent cell
    NewValue = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Cells(i + 8, 12).Value
    If NewValue <> "" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RawData").Cells(aRow + 1, aCol).Value = NewValue
    End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you considered placing the RawData into a database and querying/editing the data that way? Excel isn't really intended for the kind of thing you are wanting to achieve.

Comment: What code have you written to do the task?

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer. The code used is basically three lines iterating through the columnumbers and assigning the value to the cell at row, column.

Comment: I have considered a database solution, but it really doesnt give much benefit but it adds complexity, development time and cost.

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service. We want to help you through problems where your code breaks or just doesn't work. To do that we need to see what you've tried...so copy your code into your question..and you will probably get an answer.

Comment: OK new edit with some simple working code to get the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed it a wee bit and just to complete the dicussion I post it here. I have come to rest with the idea of using hidden fields. I have now also named all my ranges (columns) in the RawData to make life simpler and introduce less errors.

This is what I have right now. (I cannot understand how to paste code into this forum!!!)

```
Public PreviousValue As Variant
Sub Update()
Dim NewValue As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long

  'Current record in RawData is always found in cell Range Current_Record on the Summary Sheet
aRow = Range("Current_Record")

' Find the last row to update in thee Module sheet
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 8 To LastRow 'Data starts in row 8, update till last row in Module
'Save the oldValue for use in the Audit trail
PreviousValue = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "D").Value
'Column to update in RawData read from col H (Hidden value)
aCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "H").Value
'New value in adjacent cell to the left in column G
NewValue = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "G").Value
If NewValue <> "" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RawData").Cells(aRow + 1, aCol).Value = NewValue
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "G").Value = "" 'Erase the value in the Module Sheet
End If
Next i
End Sub
```